# Qt doesn't show

Tags: apt, 20.04

Qt doesn't show in my launcher.
I've tried to "sudo apt install qt5-default" (again), but I can't find the program. It's not listed on 'Installed software'.
The files are in usr/lib/qt5 etc folders, though.

Comment: If you need Qt Creator then it is contained in different package -  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/qtcreator .

Answer (score 7):

It is not supposed to be "shown" anywhere.

If you run `apt policy qt5-default`, you'll see that the package is installed.

The package contains 3 files:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/default.conf
/usr/share/doc/qt5-default/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/qt5-default/copyright
```

It also depends on `qtchooser` package that contains some executable files. But there is no `.desktop` launcher to be "shown".

You can see it at https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/qt5-default

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/qt5-default  (Ya beat me) & https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/qt5-default/filelist I would have included...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both.
I've not been accurate. Of cause the commandline programs doesn't show on the desktop. It was the IDE Qt Creator I thought I had installed. Now found to be easily installed from the Ubuntu Software Center: [image: Software center]

You have to seek qtc, not just qt, though.